# Can we know the length of the pointer returned by mxRealloc or mxMalloc?

Tags: c, matlab, mex

Given a pointer returned by `mxGetPr` or `mxRealloc`, are we still able to get its length? Since MATLAB manages memory of the pointers, does it store the meta data for us to query?

Comment: Can you use [`mxGetNumberOfElements`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxgetnumberofelements.html) or [`mxGetDimensions`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxgetnumberofelements.html)?

Comment: The length of a pointer is as for any type: `sizeof(pointer_name)`. Or do you mean the object it points to?

Comment: I think he means the number of bytes allocated.

Comment: It sounds like a stupid idea to realloc a pointer got from mxGetPr: how are you planning to inform the mxArray?

Comment: @Suever Does mxGetNumberOfElements still work if any one calls mxSetN or mxSetM? I think at that case it returns the elements set but not allocated memory.

Comment: @JoeC That may be true.

Comment: @user3528438, we could mxSetN or mxSetM after reallocation, although I agree that this seems stupid.

Comment: Look at the header file. Can you do something like `mxGetPr()->nelements_allocated`?

Comment: @FiddlingBits Do we need #include "mxinternals.h" to access nelements_allocated (http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/27806)? This header is not available to me.

Comment: Do you have `matrix.h`? Not really sure as I'm just Googling it.

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you have an `mxArray`, the size of memory pointed to by `mxGetPr` return value can be determined using `mxGetNumberOfElements`. If you're using `mxRealloc`, then you know what the new size is.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear, so let me try to explain the two functions:

- `mxGetPr` is called on an existing `mxArray` numeric array to retrieve pointer to its data (to be exact, pointer to `double` real data). If you want to know the length of this data, you can query the original array itself using `mxGetNumberOfElements`.
- `mxRealloc` and related functions are similar to the standard `malloc` family of function available in C. So if you're using them, you know what size they are since you're the one allocating the memory!

The purpose of `mxRealloc` and related functions is to allow MATLAB to auto-manage memory to some extent; so when a MEX-function returns, MATLAB takes care of releasing any registered heap memory allocated with `mxMalloc` and such.

Now writing good code means you should free your own memory (it can slow things down if you rely on this automatic memory management), but it does come in handy in certain cases (think throwing an error inside a MEX function without having to rely on ugly goto statements to ensure resources are freed on exit).

Comment: if you're interested in the internals, I think most memory allocators store the length of a heap-allocated array just before the array itself (like a header at location `ptr[-1]`). Also, the debug version of some implementations might store extra stuff in header/footer space for bound checking to catch buffer overflows.